# How to clean or reset brownie build folder

Tags: brownie, framework

Is there a command to clear/reset the brownie `build` folder (including the deployments folder)?

It would be a nice feature to have :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really, but a simple
`rm -rf {proj_dir}/build`
will suffice, as brownie kind-of expects this and handles it gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can force brownie to recompile all contracts using the following command:

```
brownie compile -a
```